# How to change src link in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I want to add `html5=1` in YouTube link. How can I do that? I try something like this:

```
function add_embed_filter($html, $url, $attr) {
$new = str_replace('oembed', 'oembed&html5=1', $html);
 return $new;
}

add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'add_embed_filter', 50, 3 );
```

but in source it look like this:
`?feature=oembed&#038;html5=1` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function add_embed_filter($html) {
    return '<div class="js-video widescreen">'.str_replace("?feature=oembed", "?html5=1", $html).'</div>';
}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'add_embed_filter', 50, 1);
```

Of course if WordPress or Youtube change how this url is constructed you will have to adapt your code accordingly, but I tested it, and this will get you there with WordPress 3.8.1. I also did not test how this works for a user who does not support HTML5 and depending on your use case, you may wish to test to ensure that this code will support them.